# Overloading Operators in Swift

Tags: swift, operator-overloading

I'm trying to implement the Comparable protocol in Swift, but the compiler doesn't like any of my attempts to overload the < operator. I've checked the Apple documents and all the SO posts, but none of them even compile. Xcode gives me this warning:

> Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

and it keeps recommending me to insert a semicolon after the less than symbol. Any insight on what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.

```
class SomeClass: NSObject, Equatable, Comparable{

    var number: UInt32!

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        self.number = arc4random()
    }

    func == (lhs: SomeClass, rhs: SomeClass) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

    func < (lhs: SomeClass, rhs: SomeClass) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You see this error, because operators have to be overloaded outside the class definition, e.g. move

```
func == (lhs: SomeClass, rhs: SomeClass) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

func < (lhs: SomeClass, rhs: SomeClass) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

outside your class definition and it will work (except for that they do not return the proper result with this implementation).